# Ionics 3 Guard issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, guard

I’ve realized that a page gets loaded before ionViewCanEnter decides, I’ve the user is even allowed to view the page.

Therefor, all the components in the template get always constructed.

IMO, this can become really inefficient, especially if the components use http request in their constructor to load data.

Am I getting something wrong or is there a better Guard approach?

**Simple Replica**

*test-page.html*

```
<ion-content>
  <test></test>
</ion-content>
```

*test-page.ts*

```
...
ionViewCanEnter() {
  console.log('ionViewCanEnter?');
  return false;
}
...
```

*test-component.ts*

```
...
constructor() {
  console.log('TestComponent Constructed');
}
...
```

*Console*

```
TestComponent Constructed
ionViewCanEnter?
```

Comment: Can you show the `code` where how you handled `ionViewCanEnter`?

Comment: I’m return a promise where I get a token from Native Storage and validate it with a (synchronous) JWT helper function:

Comment: Can you show the `code`?

Comment: @Sampath I've just added a simple version to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting something different which is against the design of the `Page/Component` in `Ionic`.

*ionViewCanEnter*

> Runs before the view can enter. This can be used as a sort of "guard"
>   in authenticated views where you need to check permissions before the
>   view can enter

You can see that it says `runs before the view can enter`.**Not** before the view has been created.If Page's `view` has been created means `components` of that `page` also being `constructed`.So that is by design.We cannot do anything for that. But you can change the way where data retrievals of your `component`. In other words, you need to emit an [**Event**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) according to the logic of the `ionViewCanEnter()` and after that, you can `subscribe` to that `event` inside your `component` for data retrievals.After that, you can remove the data retrievals inside the component's `constructor`. Hope all are working fine after that.

Comment: Seems like you’re right, but if you asked me, this guard approach causes a leak in performance: It constructs the whole page and after it says ‘hold on, you’re not even allowed to be here!’. I hope the ionic team will find a better solution in the future or enable the approach from Angular itself somehow. Anyways, good idea with the event subscription.

Comment: I don't agree here with you.You're thinking only about `false` use case. That means `hold on, you’re not even allowed to be here!`.What if `true` use case? Do you think the user should wait until the whole page has been created if it is `true`? So we'll have performance leak either way. So `Ionic/Angular` team must select one of it. They have chosen `false` use case here. And I think it is must thing too. Because without constructing the `page` they cannot even think about the `ionViewCanEnter` life cycle hook.